# Virtual machine host software

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine, qemu

I would like to create a virtual machine running Linux and a couple of network services. This virtual machine should be on a USB stick and able to run on both Windows and Linux hosts, with as little installation and access requirements as possible. All software required should be on the USB stick and there should not be any distribution restrictions in the license.

The options I have found are:

- **VMWare**: Not OK due to license issues.
- **VirtualPC**: Not OK, Windows hosts only.
- **VirtualBox**: Seems OK, but is it possible to run the host side without installation?
- **QEMU**: Seems OK, but cumbersome handling.

Are there any other options that I have missed?

Comment: The main problem with running a VM from a USB device without an installation is that you probably don't have any of the required drivers (like networking) installed.

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve here? This sounds like you'd like an isolated/secure environment to take with you? Anything speaking against making the stick bootable as a whole?

Comment: Mario, good point. My goal is to have some server software prepared to be used in technical trainings. The attendees will bring their own computers with their own set of tools to use with the server software.